# Annotations don't display on MKMapView after fetching data from GoogleMaps API

Tags: swift, api, mkmapview

I'm trying to display annotations on a MKMapView after fetching data from the GoogleMaps API. The HTTP request is successful and I can see the results in the console in the bottom of Xcode. However, when trying to display the annotations on the map, it doesn't return anything. Only mu current location (blue dot). Here is the code:

```
func plotPositions(_ data: [Any]) {

    //Remove any existing custom annotations but not the user location blue dot
    for annotation: MKAnnotation in mapView.annotations {

        if (annotation is MapPoint) {

            mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }

    //Loop through the array of places returned from the Google API
    for i in 0..<data.count {

        //Retrieve the NSDictionary object in each index of the array
        let place: [AnyHashable: Any]? = (data[i] as? [AnyHashable: Any])

        //There is a specific NSDictionary object that gives us the location info
        let geo: [AnyHashable: Any]? = (place?["geometry"] as? [AnyHashable: Any])

        // Get the lat and long for the location
        let loc: [AnyHashable: Any]? = (geo?["location"] as? [AnyHashable: Any])

        //Get the name and address info for adding to a pin
        let name: String? = (place?["name"] as? String)
        let vicinity: String? = (place?["vicinity"] as? String)

        // Create a special variable to hold this coordinate info
        var placeCoord: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)

        // Set the lat and long
        if let latitude = loc?["lat"] as? CDouble, let longitude = loc?["lat"] as? CDouble {
            placeCoord.latitude = latitude
            placeCoord.longitude = longitude
        }

        //Create a new annotation
        let placeObject = MapPoint(name: name!, address: vicinity!, coordinate: placeCoord)
        mapView.addAnnotation(placeObject)
    }
}
```

Any idea as to why it is not displaying? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
let placeObject = CustomPointAnnotation()
placeObject.coordinate = placeCoord
placeObject.title = name
placeObject.subtitle = vicinity
```

Try using a `CustomPointAnnotation` object for the annotation